# Gradle project is not able to find JavaFX Application class despite adding JavaFX plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, javafx, eclipse-plugin

I am new to both Gradle and JavaFX. I have added the JavaFX plugin to my `build.gradle` following [this](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle) and [this](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/IDE/Eclipse/Non-Modular/Gradle/hellofx/build.gradle). However, my main class `Library.java` is not able to detect the `Application` class of JavaFX when I am trying to extend it.

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java-library'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Chess.Library'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'Chess.Library'
```

**Screenshot of Library Class**

[image]

There's no `Application` from `javafx` package at all. What am I missing here?

I am using **Spring Tool Suite 4.0** as my IDE with **Buildship Gradle plugin** if that's of any help. I am also running on **Oracle Java 13**

**Edit 1:**

I have added the changes suggested and this is how my build.gradle now looks

```
plugins {
    // Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    id 'java-library'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.8'
}

repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.0-jre'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'


}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'Chess.Library'
    }
}

javafx {
    version = "13"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls' ]
}

mainClassName = 'Chess.Library'
```

But the problem is still there

I also checked my **Project and External Dependencies**, there are all the libraries except for `javafx`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue myself although not sure what was causing it, but my project's buildpath had an **unbounded Java 13**. Fixing that and restarting the IDE took care of it